# Naming convention for REST endpoint

Tags: rest

Lets say I have Properties, that each have Buildings, hat each have Rooms, that each have Contracts.

How would I design for example a GET method for it?

By following a guide http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html, I am doing like this:

```
GET http://www.example.com/properties/33245/buildings/8769/rooms/44/contracts
```

This will return all contracts for room 44. The problem here is that `properties/33245/buildings/8769` part is useless, and not used, the 44 is the primary key for table `Rooms` in database, which means, I could as well as use the following convention:

```
GET http://www.example.com/rooms/44/contracts
```

Here the problem is, that what rooms are these? Maybe there are other rooms also in future.

Should I continue using the long convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem here is that properties/33245/buildings/8769 part is useless, and not used

Why is that a problem?

> Should I continue using the long convention?

Yes. A Room belongs to a Building. A Room **cannot exist without** a Building. Therefore it shouldn't have it's own 'root endpoint' (like `example.com/rooms`). It should be tied to a Building, which on it's turn is tied to a Property.

Definitely use the 'long version'.

<sub>The logic behind using the 'long version' (convention, consistency, readability perhaps, etc) is more important than the fact that `properties/33245/buildings/8769` remains unused when GETting a Room.</sub>

Comment: But how should I handle it in the backend part, I mean, should I query for database for contracts with room id 44, or I should use all these numbers in query, meaning, all contracts with room id 44, with building id 8769, with property id 33245 is returned.

Comment: @Jaanus that's up to you.  If room ids are unique you can query on just the room. If you were to query on something that's not unique, say room number, you want to include more parameters in the query